# Why do we leave out this 20 ohm resistor when tabulating the Thevenin resistance? Is it because of short circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, short-circuits

I bumped into this particular question. I approached the question in the wrong way. I took into consideration of the extra 20 ohm resistor. but the answer key doesn't seem to consider that. Is it because of short circuit? I had drawn out the original question in red.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Pclq.jpg

Comment: Please use the image icon above the edit box to upload images.

Answer (score 1):

The 20 Ohm resistor is left out because there is a short circuit across it, assuming the wire connected across it has zero resistance.

Hope this helps.